# Remove single or multiple commas at the end of lines using Notepad++ regex replace

Tags: notepad++

In an excel column, I have words that ends with a comma and do not want any commas at the end of the lines.

Here is an example:

```
Investments, 
Financial Consultant,
```

How do I get rid of these commas at the **end** of the lines using Notepad++

**End results should look like this:**

```
Investments
Financial Consultant
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Find what: `,$` or, if there are spaces after the comma: `,\h*$`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`

Comment: THank you so much Toto, you're amazing!  This worked perfectly.